# News Articles Not Completly Working With Sync System

Tags: javascript, html

So i want to show some news articles, i have an index.php file with the 2 latest news articles but it is not showing the 2 latest ones and i have a news.php file where i want to show all the articles but it only shows 2 articles, they are the same like the index.php (Community Event & Friday Rundown September 1, 2023)

news-data.js

```
// Define news data as an array of objects with HTML file names
let newsData = [
    {
        title: "Friday Rundown",
        date: "September 3, 2023",
        content: "A Friday Rundown with some news!",
        htmlFileName: "news_3.html"
    },
    {
        title: "Friday Rundown",
        date: "September 2, 2023",
        content: "A Friday Rundown with some news!",
        htmlFileName: "news_2.html"
    },  
    {
        title: "Friday Rundown",
        date: "September 1, 2023",
        content: "A Friday Rundown with some news!",
        htmlFileName: "news_1.html"
    },
    {
        title: "Community Event",
        date: "October 5, 2023",
        content: "Join us for our upcoming community event on October 15th. Don't miss out!",
        htmlFileName: "news_0.html"
    },
];

// Function to generate HTML markup for news articles with links to individual news pages
function generateNewsHTML(articles) {
    let newsHTML = '';

    articles.forEach((article) => {
        newsHTML += `
            <div class="news-article">
                <h3 class="article-title"><a href="${article.htmlFileName}">${article.title}</a></h3>
                <p class="article-date">${article.date}</p>
                <p class="article-content">${article.content}</p>
            </div>
        `;
    });

    return newsHTML;
}

// Function to display news in a specified container
function displayNews(containerId, articles) {
    const newsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);

    if (newsContainer) {
        newsContainer.innerHTML = generateNewsHTML(articles);
    }
}

// Call the displayNews function to display news on the index.html page
displayNews('latest-news', newsData.slice(0, 2)); // Display the latest two news articles on the homepage

// Call the displayNews function to display all news articles on the news.html page
displayNews('all-news', newsData); // Display all news articles on the news page
```

A part of the news.php

```
<!-- News Container -->
<div class="news-container">
    <h2> News</h2>
    <div id="all-news"></div> <!-- This is where all news will be displayed -->
</div>

<script src="news-data.js"></script> <!-- Include your JavaScript file here -->
<script>
    // Call the displayNews function to display all news articles on the news.html page
    displayNews('all-news', newsData); // Display all news articles on the news page
</script>
```

A part of the index.php

```
<div class="news-container">
        <h2> Latest News</h2>
        <div id="latest-news"></div> <!-- This is where the latest news will be displayed -->
    </div>

    <script src="news-data.js"></script> <!-- Include your JavaScript file here -->
```

I tried about everything but nothing is working.

Comment: Since this is just HTML and JavaScript, can you update this to a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which visibly demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing?

Comment: @David The weird thing is that it works fine when i do the snippet.

Comment: It works when I test it too.  Which means the problem probably isn't what/where you think it is.  Now is the time to start using your browser's debugging tools to dig into the problem a bit more and narrow it down.

Comment: @David So i added a console.log in the script and it shows it is working but it like half isn't, any idea what i can do more?

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @David Still can't get it to work and i find nothing.

Comment: We can sympathize, but I'm afraid there's little this community can do without any information about the actual problem.